# How should we use radio group in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, radio-button

I am using codeigniter framework for one of my PHP project.

In form I want to use radio button for gender.

Gender
     * Male
     * Female

With the value 1 or for male and 2 for female.

after selection radio button value should be assign to gender.

Can any tell me how to acheive this in codigniter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you be more specific? There is no special way to do this in codeigniter unless you are asking how to have the radio button selection be submitted through AJAX.

Comment: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html This explains everything !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Something like this

```
<tr><td><?php echo form_radio('gender', '1', TRUE); ?></td><td><?php echo form_label('Male', 'gender');?></td></tr>
<tr><td><?php echo form_radio('gender', '2', FALSE); ?></td><td><?php echo form_label('Female', 'gender');?></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the html tag for creating any input in codeigniter

```
 <input type="radio" name="gender" value=1 />Male
 <input type="radio" name="gender" value=2 />Female
```

Comment: Maybe he meant using the form helper (which is explained in the docs btw)

Comment: Actually I was thinking there should be some helper method where we should just send array for options for radio groups. Actually this kind of flexibility there in symfony framework. Anyway thanks a lot for response

Answer (score -1):

**in view file :**

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value=1 />Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value=2 />Female
```

**and in controller its looks like i show you below**

```
$user_type=$this->input->post('radio');
```