# codeigniter/ radio button group not working

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, radio-button

I am trying to ask the user if he wants to subscribe to a newsletter by asking, "yes" or "no".  I have defined two radio buttons as follows in my controller:

```
       $this->data['newsletter_yes'] = array(
            'name'          => 'newsletter',
            'id'            => 'newsletter_yes',
            'value'         => '1',
        );
        $this->data['newsletter_no'] = array(
            'name'          => 'newsletter',
            'id'            => 'newsletter_no',
            'value'         => '0',
        );
```

In my view file, I have the following:

```
        <?php echo form_radio('newsletter_yes'); ?>
        <?php echo form_radio('newsletter_no'); ?>
```

The html shows the following:

```
        <input type="radio" name="newsletter_yes" value=""  />
        <input type="radio" name="newsletter_no" value=""  />
```

I really want to pass in the options to the radio button by array but I cannot get the name to equal the same!  Any suggestion or ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to give **the same name** to the button group. that's how html input type radio works.

```
<?php echo form_radio('newsletter',$yes_value); ?>
<?php echo form_radio('newsletter', $no_value); ?>
```

edit: see [also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11013241/2275490)

Answer (score 0):

Create radio like this

```
echo form_radio('newsletter', 'yes', $checked_yes, 'id=newsletter_yes');
echo form_radio('newsletter', 'no', $checked_no, 'id=newsletter_no');
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would I send the array to make that though?

Comment: value of radio will not be array , it will be either `yes` or `no`, isn't it ?

Comment: yes, just yes or now.  No idea how to pass it in the array like my original question though.